# Import errors on org.eclipse packages after upgrading Eclipse Indigo to Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I have upgraded my eclipse from Indigo to Luna that time i am getting so many errors regarding plugins not imported. Please let me know if any one have idea about how to add the below plugins in Eclipse Luna. 
I am unable to add any plugins in Eclipse Luna. Can any one provide suggestions to resolve these imports?

```
org.eclipse.jface.viewers.*;
org.eclipse.jface.wizard.*;
org.eclipse.jdt.core.*;
orgeclipse.jdt.internal.core.*;
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.*;
org.eclipse.dt.core.search.*;
org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
org.eclipse.draw2d*;
org.eclipse.core.runtime.*;
org.eclipse.ui.internal.*;
org.eclipse.ui.IEditorPart;
```

Comment: What do you have in the Preferences in 'Plug-in Development > Target Platform'?

Comment: it have 865 inbuilt eclipse plugins and i have added some of the plugins but it haven't add all the plugins. it is getting more errors on org.eclipse.jface.viewers.*;org.eclipse.jface.wizard.org.eclipse.jdt.core.; not imported.

Comment: Most of the things you list above are Java package names not plugin names. For example the `org.eclipse.jface.viewers` package is in the `org.eclipse.jface` plugin.

Comment: What package of Luna are you using (eg, Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers, etc)?

Comment: i am using "eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32" IDE. I am unable to import the above packages.It was throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

In past releases of Eclipse the eclipse development plugins were only available via the build path when you enabled the plugin development environment, and there were several ways to do that.  When I went to a new release that enabled state was reset and I'd get the same kind of errors you're getting.  I found the easiest way to re-enable the plugins was to create a dummy plugin project as that has the side affect of enabling the plugin development environment.  I'd just delete the dummy project and rebuild the entire workspace.